# Issue with printing formatted string in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to parse a text document line by line and in doing so I stumbled onto some weird behavior which I believe is caused by the presence of some kind of ankh symbol (☥). I am not able to copy the real symbol here.
In my code I try to determine whether a '+' symbol is present in the first characters of each line. To see if this worked I added a print statement containing a boolean and this string.

The relevant part of my code:

```
with open(file_path) as input_file:
    content = input_file.readlines()
    for line in content:
        plus = '+' in line[0:2]
        print('Plus: {0}, line: {1}'.format(plus,line))
```

A file I could try to parse:

```
+------------------------------
row 1 with some content
+------+------+-------+-------
☥+------+------+-------+------
|  col 1 | col 2 | col 3 ...
+------+------+-------+-------
|_ valu | val |    |   dsf |..
|_ valu | valu | ...
```

What I get as output:

> Plus: True, line: +------------------------------
>
> Plus: False, line: row 1 with some content
>
> Plus: True, line: +------+------+-------+-------
>
> ♀+------+------+-------+------
>
> Plus: False, line: |  col 1 | col 2 | col 3 ...
>
> Plus: True, line: +------+------+-------+-------
>
> Plus: False, line: |_ valu | val |    |   dsf |..
>
> Plus: False, line: |_ valu | valu | ...

So my question is why does it just print the line containing the symbol without the 'Plus: True/False'. How should I solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this with the same sequence of input lines and didn't get any repeated lines.

Comment: Maybe your lines have a `\r` character in them. Try printing the `repr` version of them.

Comment: Mm I did have to insert a unicode symbol in here because I can't seem to copy the real symbol.

Comment: Is it an option to add a regex to strip out all non-useful characters?

Comment: Printing with `repr` gives `Plus: False, line: '\r\x0c+------+------+-------+------\n'`

Comment: @spijs here you have it, `\r` resets caret to line beginning.

Comment: Thanks @ŁukaszRogalski I did not know that :). Issue is indeed fixed using `replace('\r','')`

Comment: You may want to process it or not, but in ASCII, `'\x0c'` is the code for form feed. It means that the program that has created it intended to start a new page there.

Comment: That's nice to know @SergeBallesta. This will indeed be useful. Is this code causing the symbol I see?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the editor, the system, and its charset...

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the gender symbol.  It is from the [original IBM PC character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Characters) and is encoded as `0x0c`, aka `FormFeed`, aka `Ctrl-L`.

If you are parsing text data with these present, they likely were inserted to  indicate to a printer to start a new page.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed):

> Form feed is a page-breaking ASCII control character. It forces the printer to eject the current page and to continue printing at the top of another. Often, it will also cause a carriage return. The form feed character code is defined as 12 (0xC in hexadecimal), and may be represented as control+L or ^L.